# Wrapping a bar around rough surface

Tags: shrinkwrap

I am trying to wrap a "metal bar" partially around a rough surface like a statue.
How do I do this?

- I created a "metal bar" by adding a cylinder object and scaled and positioned it to the right size
- I added subdivisions to the "metal bar" so it can bend

this is how far I got.

I think the shrinkwrap modifier is a good way of achieving this, but it does not work as I had imagined.
I want the bar to stay in the x-axis plane, this can be achieved with mode 'project' in shrinkwrap and selecting the x-axis I believe but for some reason it does not project onto my statue, the bar just stays a straight bar in front of the statue.
and it should stay a bar (for some reason shrinkwrap flattens the bar like it's clay or paper when I select a different mode in shrinkwrap)

I also want the bar to behave like a semi sturdy metal bar or wire, moldable but not stuck in every corner of a dent in the statue and lay on top of the surface.

I can't get it done, please help.

here to download the stl file: https://gofile.io/d/Zbr3ff

below screenshots

[image: pic 1]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would bevel a curve to give it thickness, and have easy control over the curve shape.

1. Make a curve circle and put it in place. In your case: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> and choose Curve > Circle. Then <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Put a Shrinkwrap modifier on the curve and target the knight. Mode: Project, On Surface. Direction: Negative (only)
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and choose Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/text. Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> again but now choose Curve from Mesh/Text. Changing the curve to a mesh and then the mesh back to a curve Applies the modifier and gives us more vertices on the curve.
4. In Edit Mode <kbd>A</kbd> to select all. then hit <kbd>F3</kbd> (default search key) and type "Set Spline Type" and choose Bezier. Then hit <kbd>F3</kbd> again and type "Set Handle Type" (or press <kbd>V</kbd>) and choose Aligned.

(Alternatively you can click on the buttons next to Edit Mode in the header of the 3D Viewport. Curve > Set Spline Type > Bezier. and Control Points > Set Handle Type > Aligned.)

5. In Object Mode Scale the curve a bit bigger, 1.05 times seems suitable. Then go to Properties > Object Data Properties > Geometry > Bevel, and set the Depth Value to 0.03 m (and maybe increase the Resolution value).

[image]

6. Fine tuning:

Decimate Curve to decrees the amount of vertices. Subdivide to increase them if needed. (Both also easily found by hitting <kbd>F3</kbd> in Edit Mode).

Select vertices and press <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> and choose Segments if you want an opening in the bar curve.

And of course move the vertices around to get the exact desired shape of the bar. : )

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and choose Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/text, if you want a mesh bar in the end.

Comment: I can't find "Set Spline Type" in F3 search, I am in edit mode and pressed "A" to select all. I am new to blender, do I need a special add on?

Comment: That is weird. Not sure why that doesn't work. Alternatively you can click on one of the buttons next to Edit Mode in the header of the 3D Viewport. The one that says Curve. In the drop down menu you should also be able to find Set Spline Type. (I'll edit it to my answer.)

Comment: there is no button that says "Curve", only View, Select, Add, Mesh, Vertex, Edge, Face and UV.
I think I need to install an add on. I am using blender 2.83.2

Comment: Ah i think get i now : ) I think you have a Mesh circle, but you need a Curve circle. Point 3 in my answer might be a little confusing. It says to covert a curve to a mesh, and then convert the mesh back to a curve again. So at point 4 it should be a curve. I'll edit my answer to be a little more clear.

Comment: thank you so much man! really helpful and great explanation
I did however do something wrong; how do you scale the curve to 1.05? I scaled the curve from 14 to 1.05 in object properties (XYZ Euler). I believe I made a small mistake there so I left it to 14 instead

Comment: I scaled in delta transform, I think that's what you meant and now it looks great! Thank you so much, I still think it's hard but you are a real master :)

Comment: Sorry i didn't have time to respond sooner. Yes, I meant scale it 1.05 times, like 105%. I'll also fix it in my answer. Glad you figured it out though. Wouldn't call me a master, I'm learning every day. And try to have fun doing it : )